# CoffeeScripts classes - access to property in callback

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have simple problem. I have Foo class and at contructor I starting timer. In timer callback I want alert class property, but I will get "undefined", why?

```
class Foo
  simpleProperty: "fooBar"

  constructor: ->
    setInterval @runBar, 1 * 1000
    return

  runBar: ->
    alert @simpleProperty #undefined, why?
    return

foo = new Foo()
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the scoping of `this` (or `@` in case of CoffeeScript).

You should use a fat arrow:

```
runBar: =>
  alert @simpleProperty #fooBar
```

See it working [here](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Foo%0A%20%20simpleProperty%3A%20%22fooBar%22%0A%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout%20%40runBar%2C%201%20%2a%201000%0A%20%20%20%20return%0A%0A%20%20runBar%3A%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20alert%20%40simpleProperty%20%23undefined%2C%20why%3F%0A%20%20%20%20return%0A%0Afoo%20%3D%20new%20Foo%28%29).

Comment: Wow, very nice usage of fat arrow. This should be given as example on CoffeeScript's page.