# CoffeeScript function as parameter in node.js API

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, atom-editor

I'm writing a plugin for Atom in CoffeeScript and I'm using [this nodejs API (telegram.link)](https://github.com/enricostara/telegram.link). It has some asymetric functions so I have to pass functions as parameters which get called as callback. My problem is that when I use the following code:

```
login: ->
    console.log 'Loging in'
    @client = telegramLink.createClient({
        id: config.telegram.prod.app.id,
        hash: config.telegram.prod.app.hash,
        version: '0.0.1',
        lang: 'en'
    },
    config.telegram.prod.primaryDataCenter);
    @client.createAuthKey(@authCallback)
    console.log @client

authCallback: (auth) ->
    console.log auth
    @client.auth.sendCode(config.telegram.test.telNr, 5, 'en', @sendCodeCallback)
```

which gets compiled to:

```
login: function() {
  console.log('Loging in');
  this.client = telegramLink.createClient({
    id: 12345,
    hash: 'q1w2e3r4t5y6u7i8o9p0',
    version: '0.0.1',
    lang: 'en'
  }, config.telegram.prod.primaryDataCenter);
  this.client.createAuthKey(this.authCallback);
  return console.log(this.client);
},
authCallback: function(auth) {
  console.log(auth);
  return this.client.auth.sendCode(config.telegram.test.telNr, 5, 'en', this.sendCodeCallback);
}
```

`@client` is undefined in the authCallback function.

I read on Stackoverflow ([CoffeeScripts classes - access to property in callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397440/coffeescripts-classes-access-to-property-in-callback)) that I should use `=>` (fat-arrow) so I tried this resulting in the following compiled script:

```
authCallback: (function(_this) {
  return function(auth) {
    console.log(auth);
    return _this.client.auth.sendCode(config.telegram.test.telNr, 5, 'en', _this.sendCodeCallback);
  };
})(this)
```

But `@client` remains undefined. I think that maybe the callback function call out of the API doesn't work properly anymore.

What else can I do to keep the original scope, but make it work with the API?

Comment: How does `authCallback` get called? Keep in mind that `this` in a (Java|Coffee)Script function depends on how the function is called rather than how or where it is defined (except for bound functions of course). Using `=>` should do the trick. Have you looked at what `@` is inside `authCallback`? Are you sure you're calling `login` first? Are you sure you're calling `login` and `authCallback` on the same object?

Comment: @muistooshort From the API's source code `if (callback) {
        this.client.once('sendCode', callback);
    }`. The API is written in pure nodejs and not in CoffeeScript so there is not `@` at all. Yes, I'm sure i called login first, because it is triggered by a menu button in Atom. If you want to see my whole project code I've shared it on [Github](https://github.com/Morosko/atom-telegram)

Comment: `@` is CoffeeScript's shorthand for `this` so `@` is there. I don't know what `this.client.once('sendCode', callback)` does so you'll have to dig deeper. Or you could `console.log(@)` in `authCallback` and see for yourself.

Comment: Please make answers answers, not part of the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution:

Today I found my solution for the problem.
Now my code looks like so:

```
login: ->
console.log 'Logging in'
@client =
  telegramLink.createClient({
    id: config.telegram.prod.app.id
    hash: config.telegram.prod.app.hash
    version: '0.0.1'
    lang: 'en'
  }
  config.telegram.prod.primaryDataCenter)
@client.createAuthKey((auth) =>
  console.log @client.auth
  @client.auth.sendCode(
    config.telegram.test.telNr,
    5,
    'en',
    @sendCodeCallback))
console.log @client
```

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the indetion of your code, I would guess that you are not inside a class. If you are not inside a instance of a class "this" or "@" will not work. The second thing is that the the definition of the callback. It should be not defined as a method of your class. The class could look something like this:

```
class MyClass
  constructor: ->
    // do something
  login: ->
    @client = telegramLink.createClient({
        id: config.telegram.prod.app.id,
        hash: config.telegram.prod.app.hash,
        version: '0.0.1',
        lang: 'en'

     @client.authCallback: (auth) =>
       console.log auth
       @client.auth.sendCode(config.telegram.test.telNr, 5, 'en', @sendCodeCallback)
```

That your class thing works you need to create an instance so maybe that is not what you want.

You could change your code that it works like you defined it just with functions.

```
login: ->
    console.log 'Loging in'
    client = telegramLink.createClient({
        id: config.telegram.prod.app.id,
        hash: config.telegram.prod.app.hash,
        version: '0.0.1',
        lang: 'en'
    },
    config.telegram.prod.primaryDataCenter);
    client.createAuthKey(@authCallback)
    console.log @client

authCallback: (auth) ->
  console.log auth
  client.auth.sendCode(config.telegram.test.telNr, 5, 'en', sendCodeCallback)
```

Hint: the definition of your options dictionary inside the createClient method looks like JS and not like Coffescript. Also the ";" you should not use.
To mix the definitions could also create some mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My code is in a class. Thanks for the hint with the mixture of JS and CoffeeScript. I just copied it from the API's documentation.